# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror, this, react-props

I was trying to implement stack navigation and I got this error it says that this. props give the error I tried :

- deleting this.props because I used  function in App.js it didn't work

I have tried many solutions and cannot find a good answer please do explain your answer so that everyone can understand it very well

here is my code

APP.JS

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    
 import Login from './pages/Login';
 import Register from './pages/Register';


const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function MystackNav(){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Register' component={Register} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}


export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MystackNav/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

LOGIN.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
    useColorScheme,
    Image,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

import Register from './Register';



export default class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.container2}>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput placeholder='username' placeholderTextColor={'#e02b70'} maxLength={12} style={styles.textinput}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput placeholder='password' placeholderTextColor={'#e02b70'} secureTextEntry={true} style={styles.textinput}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    **<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} 
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>**
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

here is the error

```
o reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

 BUNDLE  ./index.js

 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

Comment: Where are you using `this`? There's no reference to it in your code.
Also, can you include the full error message?

Comment: If there is no reason to make `Login` a class component, then make it a function component

Comment: Can you add the exact error in the question ? 
That would be more helpful.

Comment: were you using this.props or props in your components or was it an error from the library? Are styles/navigation global variables (or from imports that you tripped out) or should they come from the properties?

Comment: @Tom,@Kailash,@user3252327 Ihave added the complete error message for a better understanding this.props were used inside the touchable highlight in the login class

Comment: Your error message indicates that your error is coming from `index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Login class likewise :

```
//import Register from './Register'; //because you are not using this in your Login Class

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container2}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput placeholder='username' placeholderTextColor={'#e02b70'} maxLength={12} style={styles.textinput}></TextInput>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TextInput placeholder='password' placeholderTextColor={'#e02b70'} secureTextEntry={true} style={styles.textinput}></TextInput>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} 
                onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for the response but the error is still the same and its not solved

Comment: can you comment out the onPress prop and then check, If issue persist that means its coming from some other file or component might be from Register component.